# Defining Javascript class prototype methods

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I defined a class like this at first:

```
function mapTile(nx,ny)
{
    //members
    this.x = nx;
    this.y = ny;

    //methods
    this.prototype.visible = function(){return true;};
    this.prototype.getID = function(){return y*tiles_per_line+x;};
    this.prototype.getSrc = function(){return 'w-'+this.getID+'.png';}
};
```

Which throws an exception when I try to create an object:

```
t=new mapTile(1,1)
TypeError: Cannot set property 'visible' of undefined
```

in Chromium and fails silently in Firefox(with firebug)

This works OK though:

```
function mapTile(nx,ny)
{
    //members
    this.x = nx;
    this.y = ny;
};

//methods
//this.prototype.xx=1;
mapTile.prototype.visible = function(){return true;};
```

What is the proper way to implement prototype methods inside the body?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the proper way to implement prototype methods inside the body?

You may not like this answer: *don't* define them inside the body, since that would re-define them every time the constructor runs for that object.  Define them like you have working, with `objectType.prototype...` after it's declared.

Prototype methods are there specifically to be shared amongst all instances, what you're doing is somewhere in-between, you either want them declared inside specific to that instance, like this:

```
function mapTile(nx,ny)
{
    //members
    this.x = nx;
    this.y = ny;

    //methods
    this.visible = function(){return true;};
    this.getID = function(){return y*tiles_per_line+x;};
    this.getSrc = function(){return 'w-'+this.getID+'.png';}
}
```

Or shared on the prototype outside, like this:

```
function mapTile(nx,ny)
{
    //members
    this.x = nx;
    this.y = ny;
}
mapTile.prototype.visible = function(){return true;};
mapTile.prototype.getID = function(){return y*tiles_per_line+x;};
mapTile.prototype.getSrc = function(){return 'w-'+this.getID+'.png';}
```